# NoReverseMatch at / Django e python

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to creat a new app but I am getting this error 'NoReverseMatch at'

This is my project urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('app_infos_gerais.urls') )
]
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app_infos_gerais',
]
```

My app urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    
    path('infosgerais/', views.infos_gerais, name="resultado_infos_gerais")
```

My app view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


# Create your views here.

def infos_gerais(request):
    return HttpResponse('Olá, teste!')
```

My app html

```
{% extends 'modelo-tratore.html' %}

{% block pagetitle %} 
Dados gerais
{% endblock %}

{% load static %}
{% block conteudo %}

{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}

<div>
    <p>Teste</p>
</div>
```

And the file where Im trying to call the url

```
<li class="p-3">
    <a href="{% url 'resultado_infos_gerais' %}">Infos gerais</a>
</li>
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

I tried everything I found but nothing worked.

Comment: The Django error view has a *Switch to copy-and-paste view* button. Use this to copy the *full* traceback and [edit] the question including this traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your view is `resultado_infos_gerais`, but in your template, you use `'resultado_infos_geraisß'`, you also used an `app_name` in the `urls.py`, so that means you need to use a namespace, so:

```
<a href="{% url 'app_infos_gerais:resultado_infos_gerais' %}">Infos gerais</a>
```

Comment: Hey Willem. Thanks, the {% url 'app_infos_gerais:resultado_infos_gerais' %} was just a typing mistake, they were ok in my code. 

About the app_name, I fixed it as you suggested but doesn`t work, I keep getting the error. I also tried to delete the app_name and use just the <a href="{% url 'resultado_infos_gerais' %}">Infos gerais</a> but doesn`t work too.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the traceback?